# Couldn't able to add cocoa pod files (which is created using "pod lib create") for sample example?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, cocoapods

I have created a new cocoa pod using

```
pod lib create SamplePod
```

It set me up with a well thought out library structure. So I created new file by making a group (SamplePod) inside Pod folder "Sample.h" and when trying to access it using

```
#import <SamplePod/Sample.h>
```

It couldn't able to identify the file.
Can anybody explain where to add new files for pod and how to refer them in pod sample project ?

I have already refered these links

(1) http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create

(2) http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html

Answer (score 1):

You should store files that are actually part of your `CocoaPod` in the the location specified for `source_files` in your `podspec` (e.g. Pod/Classes).

So, if you are adding new files, you should put them in that directory, and you can then put them in a sensible group folder within Xcode.

If you are copying an existing file to the project (that is part of your actual pod), you should copy them to the same directory above, and you can then add them to your example project by going to `File > Add Files to "MyProject" ...` (you should un-tick the `Copy items to destination group's folder`).

They can then be imported with the usual `#import "MyFile.h"`

Comment: Ok, that means I have to manually add these files to sample project of that pod Itself. There is no way I can refer them directly because both exists in same workspace eg. samplepod.xcodeproj and pod.xcodeproj?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to run

```
Pod install
```

After adding new files. Then you can easily import these files to your CocoaPod sample project.For more details you might want to check [this out](https://iosmonk.wordpress.com/2014/08/25/be-a-pro-at-cocoa-pods-in-a-day/)